# Trying to hide a div onClick on a button that is a child of said div

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery and HTML so forgive me if I am making a really noob mistake. I have a div with a button side of it. When the user is done reading it, I want them to be able to close the div.

```
<div class="modalDiv">
 blah blah blah
 <p class="center"><input type="button" onclick="$(this).parent().hide()" value="x"></p>
 </div>
```

But every time someone clicks the button, it doesn't actually hide the div :(

The button disappears but the div stays on screen. Why is parent() not getting the main div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.parent()` will pull the HTML element that is "wrapping" the button in question. It does not actually look for divs because a "parent" can be anything really.

In this case, the DOM is actually `div->p->input` so when you call `.parent()` on `this`, you are actually selecting the `<p>` because that is the parent of the div.

There are two solutions:

(a) you can select the parent (div) of the parent (p) as such:

`$(this).parent().parent().hide()`

or, (b) you can find the "nearest" div with class `modalDiv` to the element in question

`$(this).closest('div.modalDiv').hide()`

I would suggest (A) for you as your HTML isn't too complicated or overly nested.

Good Luck

Comment: Liked your answer. You elaborated it quite well.

Comment: Arghh, thanks so much for pointing this out so clearly. I feel silly now.

Comment: @nikhil Thanks :) - George No worries ;)

Answer (score 0):

To hide div you need to update

```
$(this).parent().hide()
```

to

```
$(this).parent().parent().hide()
```

The reason being the parent of input is `p` and not `div`. So if you need to hide the div you need to go to the parent of `p` and then hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably a better way than using parent() is to focus directly on the class with jquery.

`$('.modalDiv').hide();`

The benefits of doing it this way is it is now de-coupled from your HTML. Wherever the button appears in the children you can guarantee the correct div will be hidden when it's clicked, meaning you have less of a problem with maintenanc in the future.

You have also to consider that as your HTML gets more complex, do you end up with `.parent()` called *n* times? `.closest()` doesn't suffer from this problem though.

It's also a bit clearer, as a developer looking at your stuff for the first time I can look at the js and see immediately what it does, rather than having to refer to the HTML and assess the structure.